# Navigating inside a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

I have a dialog with a button inside. When the button is clicked, I want the action to be rendered inside the same dialog (replacing the current content). Is that possible?

For now, I have this code, but is doesn't render the action inside the dialog, it simply redirects the whole page.

```
<button style="float: right" class="awe-btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Agenda", new { paramid = Model.ID })'">
    @:Modify
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keith's answer is right. I'm just providing a more complete example.

This is the **controller**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult WhatTimeIsIt()
        {
            return Json(DateTime.Now.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

And the **view**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showModal() {
            $('#TheModal').modal('show');
        }

        function whatTimeIsIt() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/whattimeisit',
                type: 'GET'
            }).done(function (data) {
                showCurrentTime(data);
            });
        }

        function showCurrentTime(data) {
            $('#TheModal .modal-header h3').html('Current time and date from the server');
            $('#TheModal .modal-body').html(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal(); return false;">Show the modal window!</button>

    <div class="modal hide" id="TheModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>This is your modal</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Modal content goes here.
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whatTimeIsIt(); return false;">What time is it?</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how the event must be handled by the javascript. This is an AJAX call with DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do an ajax call and replace the inner contents of the dialog on success. You can't do it your current way because that will cause a full page refresh. The dialog is just a div positioned to display on top of the screen, not a separate iFrame or anything.

Add a data attribute called data-action with the action you want to execute then do something like this:

```
$('.awe-btn').click(function(e) {
   var url  = $(e.target).data('action');
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET'
   }).done(function(html) {
       $('.my-modal').html(html);
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you give some more details for an implementation? I can't figure it out